# How Can I Use An Email Address From A Domain To Register The Same Domain

Tags: email, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I want to register a domain called webmasters.com. Can I enter admin@webmasters.com as the contact email when filing for the domain name? The forseeable problem is that the email address has not yet been set up at the time of registration, but could be configured shortly thereafter.

I do not have an alternate permanent email I want to use for this purpose. This may seem like a simple question, but I have never registered a domain name and do not know how the process works from start to finish... or whether that email addres will be used immediatelly for verification purposes.

Comment: I **HIGHLY** recommend **AGAINST** this! One of the clients in the company I'm working did *exactly* what you describe. The final result: a complete mess! We spent a few hours and we exchanged emails back and forth and we waited almost a week for the domain to be accessible again. Don't do this to yourself.

Comment: Don't do this... just create a free email address or something, as long as you don't use an email address for the domain itself. Providers often send very important information to that email address which you will, in that case, not receive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you use your existing email while registering a domain name. When you complete the domain registration process, most domain providers send domain info, account activation links, invoice & billing info to email address which you put in during registration.

Once you create account and register domain then you can easily create new email and change it for that account also.

Comment: Thank you. I'm mainly asking because some people have suggested submitting fake info, which can result in the loss of your domain, but also suggested that maybe an email wasn't sent right away. Once the email address under the new domain was created, then the information _would_ be correct. But apparently, there is information that is sent right away in some cases. Is this the email address that appears in the whois datbase, or is it for the registrar's own purpose? My main concern is that I wouldn't want any record of the temporary email address used, once the new email address is submitted.

Comment: Yes exactly, In this type of cases all details we should put correct when register.

Comment: Will do, but can you comment on my last edit to the first comment first? Is the email address you submit to the registrar the email address that appears in the whois database, or is it kept by the registrar? I would prefer the temporary email used to register the domain remain private after the new admin@webmasters.com is created.

Comment: Yes that email we display in WHO.IS , About privacy you can request to domain provider. Now a days most of domain provider allow user to hide their info from anywhere.

Comment: And , yes you will get verification immediately once you complete register process. Now all domain provider ask for activation link so it is depends.

Answer (score 6):

I would *never* have a domain registration using an email address in the same domain, either at registration, (which is impossible anyway) or later.

The reason why is:

Let's say you have a technical problem with the domain that is preventing mail from being delivered. Bad MX records or some other DNS problem, for example. Or your mail server just took a dump and you need to change the MX records temporarily. You try to login at the registrar, but you forgot your password. They will then attempt to email you at an address you can't receive mail at!

Getting out of a situation like this can be anywhere from hairy to impossible, depending on the registrar and perhaps other factors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it. I had a client for whom I registered the domain using my own email ID but later when I edited the email ID from the domain panel to an email created on the same domain.

I won't recommend you to do the same for registration. You might receive notifications or probably verification links during registering. You don't want the emails to go nowhere.

Comment: I like your 'can do' attitude, but with a bit of caution. +1

Comment: Out of curiosity: from another [post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47723/how-long-does-it-take-a-whois-server-to-update) it sounds like a WHOIS update may take a while depending on your host. Do you know 1. How long it takes the new email take (on average) to update in the public WHOIS database? and 2. Is there any record, public or otherwise, of the original email used?

Comment: It varies from company to company. For example, I have noticed that GoDaddy has a decent update time while updating its whois data. My registrar says it takes between 24-48 hours.

Comment: There are a whole lot of bots out there who would pick your whois data at the same time, they the dynamic data does get updated from time to time which is a good news.